# Typescript w Webpack import legacy javascript class_1.class is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a project which I am migrating to Typescript from Javascript. There is a lot of Legacy Javascript which was previously not set up to be exported/imported, but just concatenated together.  I am trying to import the legacy Javascript classes into the Typescript code, but am getting errors when trying to create a new instance of the imported javascript class.

I am using Webpack to build the final app.js file.  Babel is being run in Webpack.

**Directory structure:**

```
webpack.config.js
tsconfig.json
.babelrc
legacy-js/
--LegacyJSClass.js
new-ts/
--NewTSClass.ts
ts-build/
--legacy-js/
----LegacyJSClass.js
----LegacyJSClass.js.map
--new-ts/
----NewTSClass.js
----NewTSClass.js.map
dist/
--webpack-output-file.js
```

**./legacy-js/LegacyJSClass.js:**

```
class LegacyJSClass {
    constructor(data) {
        data = data || {};
        this.ExampleJsProp = data.ExampleProp;
    }
}

export { LegacyJSClass };
```

**./new-ts/NewTSClass.ts**

```
import { LegacyJSClass } from "../legacy-js/LegacyJSClass";

export class NewTSClass {
    ExampleTsProp: any = new LegacyJSClass();
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.ExampleTsProp);
    }
}

let tsClass = new NewTSClass();
```

**./tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./ts-build",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "traceResolution": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "./new-ts/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**./webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

module.exports = {
    name: 'app',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new ManifestPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js%/,
                loader: 'eslint',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'source-map-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ['env']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    entry: __dirname + '/new-ts/NewTSClass',
    output: {
        filename: 'webpack-output-file.js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist'
    },
    eslint: {
        failOnWarning: false,
        failOnError: true
    },
    externals: {
        "jquery": "jquery"
    }
};
```

**./.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [ "env" ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-remove-export" // This removes the export statements from the LegacyJS since it is still contatenated together and output as one big file and doesn't use a module loader.
  ]
}
```

Everything compiles correctly, however when I try to load `webpack-output-file.js` in the browser it gives me the error:

```
NewTSClass.ts:20 Uncaught TypeError: LegacyJSClass_1.LegacyJSClass is not a constructor
    at new NewTSClass (NewTSClass.ts:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (NewTSClass.ts:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 4a128ff…:19)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (bootstrap 4a128ff…:39)
    at bootstrap 4a128ff…:39
```

Upon further investigation, it appears that Typescript is moving everything over correctly:

**./ts-build/legacy-js/LegacyJSClass.js**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var LegacyJSClass = (function () {
    function LegacyJSClass(data) {
        data = data || {};
        this.ExampleJsProp = data.ExampleProp;
    }
    return LegacyJSClass;
}());
exports.LegacyJSClass = LegacyJSClass;
//# sourceMappingURL=LegacyJSClass.js.map
```

**./ts-build/new-ts/NewTSClass.js**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var LegacyJSClass_1 = require("../legacy-js/LegacyJSClass");
var NewTSClass = (function () {
    function NewTSClass() {
        this.ExampleTsProp = new LegacyJSClass_1.LegacyJSClass();
        console.log(this.ExampleTsProp);
    }
    return NewTSClass;
}());
exports.NewTSClass = NewTSClass;
var tsClass = new NewTSClass();
//# sourceMappingURL=NewTSClass.js.map
```

However, when these are run through Webpack/babel... they are transformed differently:

**./dist/webpack-output-file.js**

/******/

// Webpack bootstrap stuff...

```
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var LegacyJSClass_1 = __webpack_require__(1);
    var NewTSClass = (function () {
        function NewTSClass() {
            this.ExampleTsProp = new LegacyJSClass_1.LegacyJSClass();
            console.log(this.ExampleTsProp);
        }
        return NewTSClass;
    }());
    exports.NewTSClass = NewTSClass;
    var tsClass = new NewTSClass();

/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {
    "use strict";

    var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

    var LegacyJSClass = function LegacyJSClass(data) {
        _classCallCheck(this, LegacyJSClass);

        data = data || {};
        this.ExampleJsProp = data.ExampleProp;

    };

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
// Sourcemap info...
```

I have tried every different method I can find and cannot get this to work.  If I change the js module export to `export default LegacyJSClass` it will give the error `LegacyJSClass_1.default is not a constructor`.

Ultimately the reason I want this to work is because I don't want to have to create defined type files for every legacy class that is used, and there are too many to dedicate to porting to typescript right away.  The rest of the application still uses the legacy js, so it must continue to work while the new Typescript is being developed and slowly released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `babel-plugin-transform-remove-export`, which removes all exports from the JavaScript files and the comment in your `.babelrc` is not correct when using webpack (it might have been a leftover from your old build system). Webpack uses the actual exports, just the exports object is provided by webpack to make it work in the browser. The import you're trying to use does not exist in the module that has been processed by babel, as you can see in your webpack output there is no export in the module 1. If you try to log out `LegacyJSClass` in your TypeScript file, you'll see that it's `undefined` and `undefined` is not a constructor (frankly, the error messages is not very informative).

You have to remove the plugin from your `.babelrc` and you also don't need to configure the presets again in your webpack config on the `babel-loader`, since it will use the `.babelrc`.

```
{
  "presets": [ "env" ]
}
```

Comment: This worked. I was unaware that the webpack babel config would access my babelrc if it was already defined in the webpack config.  The babelrc was being used by an old gulp process that concats all of the old JS.  The export remove was included because there is no module loader for that legacy JS.  I put the babel settings directly in the gulp-babel plugin declaration, and removed the transform-remove-export plugin from my babelrc, and everything works great.  Thanks!